# Best Practices / Solution Architecture on initial Icons Delivery to Mobile App in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, sqlite, architecture, mobile-application

here is a question from a total beginner in mobile app development :)

I am building a React Native application for iOS platform first. I am stuck with decision on **how to deliver icons to the application**. Imagine:

1. I have a reference data set with eg travelling options (bike, motorbike, etc).
2. The actual set is much bigger though - I am expecting rather 100-200 items with one icon each for the UI.
3. These should be cached in the application.
4. Most of them wont change, new ones might come to the set periodically, but not even every week.

**Now to the options I was thinking of:**

1. Deliver a sqlite database with images as BLOB and update the database when new icons arrive
2. Deliver a sqlite database with image URLs for S3 bucket items and update the database when new icons arrive
3. Deliver the app with initial sqlite bundled with BLOB or URLs(?) and update over the air when new icons arrive
4. Do not use sqlite database at all and deliver all with REST API call on startup with image URLs. Load images when needed and cache them. Update database with new icon URLs when new icons arrive.

I think I tend to be using Option 4 because it seems least heavy on the client - he can always download the icon whenever he needs one. But it also has a latency because of downloading the icon for the first time from private s3 bucket.
However I am missing real-world experience in mobile apps and probably missing important details. Hoping for some insight from experts. Thanks for any pro and con you can deliver on this options!

Answer (score 1):

You are right, no database needed at all.
So basically you have to load those icons only once and cache them inside the app. You can you something like `react-native-fast-image` or do caching by yourself.
If URL of icon was changed - the new image will be cached.

So on real-world apps, you usually have the image placeholders (example below) or loaders (more rare). [image]

If you have multiple types of vehicle, you can create multiple placeholders and show them unless the original image is loading/not available.

Comment: Thanks! Gives me some security about the decision :)

Answer (score 0):

Using react native firebase storage and firestore is a good option. The images can be loaded remotely and the caching is done automatically

Comment: I have not heard about this before, but from description on the website it seems to be an overkill for my use case.. I dont need devices sync and my data doesnt change that often. Unless you have more specific benefits for my usecase, I dont think this is any better than sqlite or any other database.. am I wrong?